# What is the strategy that WordPress uses to handle pages called?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

WordPress uses the following `.htaccess` code to intercept all HTTP requests and redirect them to `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

What is this strategy called? Is it that REST thing I keep hearing about? Is it a common strategy that is used elsewhere? I want to know so that I can look up discussions of the pros/cons of using this strategy over others, and whether it's considered a good practice or not, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with REST at all.

It's URL rewriting as part of an implementation of the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

It is a common strategy to redirect requests to a certain script. This particular way of doing it is appropriate to certain environments, such as Wordpress running on an Apache web server. Some systems use completely different architecture - running nodes for example you would handle routing very differently.

What it allows you to do is to serve pages which don't correspond to a physical file. For a CMS like Wordpress you can add many posts and pages, together with other content which may have it's own url. They aren't all going to be unique html files full of content - instead they are generated from a common set of code. url rewriting makes this possible.

[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is something else altogether. It is a way that web services talk to each other. For example, if you want to say get me the events for this date, or save this new blog post, you can create code to do that which is "RESTful".

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I appreciate the info in your answer.